# How do you say "do a plank" in Chinese?

Tags: terminology, sport

[image: This is a person doing a plank.]

Here is a person doing a "plank". What would you say in Chinese?

Comment: Curiously, this question got an answer [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/SkritterHQ/status/1287842104111136771).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The position is called:

> 平板撑
>
> ping2 ban3 cheng1

平板 meaning literally "plank", or "slab", and 撑 standing for 支撑 "to prop up".

The longer form 平板支撑 is also common.

---

About the verb "how to do" a plank, that would be simply **做** but also **完成** might be fine.

> 如何完成平板支撑 How to do/complete planks

Answer (score 2):

plank means 平板支撑，do a plank we can say 做一组平板支撑