# How do I say the exercises "Bridges", "Supermans", "Scissor kicks", "Wall sits", "Lying lateral leg lifts", and "Side planks" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, terminology, sport

I would like to know how to say the following exercises in Chinese:

1. Bridges
   [image: A bridge]
2. Supermans
   [image: A superman]
3. Scissor kicks
   [image: A scissor kick]
4. Wall sits
   [image: A wall sit]
5. Lying lateral leg lifts
   [image: A lying lateral leg lift]
6. Side planks
   [image: A side plank]

Google Translate gives: 1. 橋 2. 超人 3. 剪刀腳 4. 牆坐 5. 臥式抬腿 6. 側板. The issue is that I have no way to tell whether these are the correct terms for the exercises, or just literal word-for-word copies in Chinese.

Comment: I "voted" to close without noticing the comment.  Anyway I [edit]ed the comment into the question, so I better reopen it (and the comment is no longer needed).  The answer to "plank" is here: [How do you say "do a plank" in Chinese?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/39672)

Comment: Have you tried searching the proposed Chinese translation and see what images you get? Aside, I'd be surprised if any of them are legible. 侧卧抬腿 is how I would translate 5. It is the only one close to what you got. I don't know what the other items do. (And so if you extrapolate me to others, perhaps sharing some links/pictures would help.)

Comment: I have added pictures to help clarify. Googling 橋 gives pictures of bridges; 超人 gives pictures of Superman (TM). 剪刀腳 yields mostly pictures of some kind of leg-crossing/leg-choking activity. 牆坐 gives pictures of wall-sits, so it may be correct. 臥式抬腿  shows some lying lateral leg lifts, and some people with their legs up against the wall. 側板 shows at least one side-plank picture, the rest being pictures of the sides of computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned move 2, 4, 5 and variants of move 1, 3 from a trainer and dance teacher. My translation will come from or be inspired by her version. She is rather senior. So some of the moves have been known and practiced in China for decades, where I expect the terminology to be more stable and uniform. As well, in China, a unique-ish form of body training called 形体 emerged over the recent decades, where people use moves adapted from basic dancing training/college for general exercise. Those moves tend to have uniform terminology. In other cases, moves that became popular later should have more diverse terminology.

1. 仰卧撑

仰卧 means lying facing up. 撑 means push up or pushing up.

I can't remember if there is a standard name for such a move. There might be a different standard name for having your two arms in a flat position.

拱桥腿 is used by [some](https://image.baidu.com/search/index?tn=baiduimage&ps=1&ct=201326592&lm=-1&cl=2&nc=1&ie=utf-8&word=%E6%8B%B1%E6%A1%A5%E8%85%BF). 拱桥 means rainbow bridge. I prefer descriptive naming myself -- not metaphoric. My preference is a bit "German-like" (and arguably wider Chinese preference too).

2. [俯卧四肢向上](https://image.baidu.com/search/index?tn=baiduimage&ps=1&ct=201326592&lm=-1&cl=2&nc=1&ie=utf-8&word=%E4%BF%AF%E5%8D%A7%E5%9B%9B%E8%82%A2%E5%90%91%E4%B8%8A)

四肢 - the four limbs

向上 - towards up (if you are into language, this is a rare case of preposition conjugated into verb)

四肢向上 for short also works. Since you can't do this move in any other way.

3. You need to disambiguate.

If you mean lying flat, kicking one leg up while fixing the other leg on the floor, (head should be on the floor, arms are relaxed) then

仰卧前踢腿

Memory is vague on this one. But this version conveys the point.

仰卧 - lying facing up

踢腿 - kicks

前踢腿 - front kicks

So this combo differentiates from the possible sick kicks. It is inferred that you do not kick with both legs, because it is not productive to do so. (Raising both legs slowly is called 仰卧**抬腿**. 抬 means lift. The *both* part is inferred because it makes no sense to lift one leg.)

If you mean raising both legs, raising one more while losing one and alternate, (head area should be raised, but legs should not be near 90 degree up,) then

交叉抬腿

交叉 means cross

Obviously, be careful to not hurt the neck.

4. Various possibilities:

[背靠墙蹲](https://image.baidu.com/search/index?tn=baiduimage&ps=1&ct=201326592&lm=-1&cl=2&nc=1&ie=utf-8&word=%E8%83%8C%E9%9D%A0%E5%A2%99%E8%B9%B2)

[靠墙蹲起](https://image.baidu.com/search/index?tn=baiduimage&ps=1&ct=201326592&lm=-1&cl=2&nc=1&ie=utf-8&word=%E9%9D%A0%E5%A2%99%E8%B9%B2%E8%B5%B7)

The search links themselves offer more possibilities.

5. Various possibilities:

躺地踢旁腿

侧躺踢旁腿

侧卧踢腿

侧卧抬腿

Notably, [侧卧旁踢](https://image.baidu.com/search/index?tn=baiduimage&ps=1&ct=201326592&lm=-1&cl=2&nc=1&ie=utf-8&word=%E4%BE%A7%E5%8D%A7%E6%97%81%E8%B8%A2) seems to not work even though it should be fairly unambiguous.

躺地 means lying on the floor

躺 means lying (down)

踢旁腿 means kicking towards the side

侧 means side

侧卧, 侧躺 means lying on your side (at which point kicking to the side is the only sensible thing to to)

踢腿 means kick

抬腿 means lifting leg

So, if you mean kick, then don't say 抬腿; if you mean lift, use 抬腿 or 举腿 (not used in this case)

6. 侧卧撑

In specific context, I expect 侧板撑 or 侧板支撑 or 斜板支撑 to be legitimate since 平板支撑 has been accepted for plank. However, none of them yields the correct search result.

Meanwhile, 侧卧撑 is immediately comprehensible because 俯卧撑 means push-up.

Comment: I want to say a huge thank you to Argyll! I hope this video can disambiguate 3., the scissor kick: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ap4DqnKmrqc

Comment: @CTVK: You are welcome :) 交叉抬腿 is exactly that. Moreover, 交叉抬腿 is commonly taught together a side version of split movement in the same pose. Does that check out?